# Should I RLock map before range?

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency

Is it safe to range map without locking if multiple goroutines will run notifyAll func? Actually in a range I need to sometimes remove entries from a map.

```
var mu sync.RWMutex

func (self *Server) notifyAll(event *Event)
  ch := make(chan int, 64)
  num := 0
  for k, v := range self.connections {
    num++
    ch <- num

    go func(int k, conn *Conn) {
      err := conn.sendMessage(event)
      <-ch
      if err != nil {
        self.removeConn(k)
      }
    }(k, v)
  }
}

func (self *Server) removeConn(int k) {
  mu.Lock()
  defer mu.Unlock()
  delete(self.connections, k)
}

// Somewhere in another goroutine
func (self *Server) addConn(conn *Conn, int k) {
  mu.Lock()
  defer mu.Unlock()
  self.connections[k] = conn
}
```

Or I must RLock map before range?

```
func (self *Server) notifyAll(event *Event)
  mu.RLock()
  defer mu.RUnlock()
  // Skipped previous body...
}
```

Comment: What is your problem with `self`, is it a kind of OCD?

Comment: it's actually looked down upon by the Go creators themselves, along with the majority of the community. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names also check http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/286406/use-of-this-in-golang

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: maps are not concurrent-safe (one can still say thread-safe) in Go.

So, if you need to access a map from different go-routines, you must employ some form of access orchestration, otherwise "uncontrolled map access can crash the program" (see [this](https://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps)).

**Edit:**

This is another implementation (without considering housekeeping concerns - timeouts, quit, log, etc) which ignores the mutex all-together and uses a more Goish approach (this is just for demonstrating this approach which helps us to clear access orchestration concerns - might be right or not for your case):

```
type Server struct {
    connections map[*Conn]struct{}

    _removeConn, _addConn chan *Conn
    _notifyAll            chan *Event
}

func NewServer() *Server {
    s := new(Server)
    s.connections = make(map[*Conn]struct{})
    s._addConn = make(chan *Conn)
    s._removeConn = make(chan *Conn, 1)
    s._notifyAll = make(chan *Event)
    go s.agent()
    return s
}

func (s *Server) agent() {
    for {
        select {
        case c := <-s._addConn:
            s.connections[c] = struct{}{}
        case c := <-s._removeConn:
            delete(s.connections, c)
        case e := <-s._notifyAll:
            for c := range s.connections {
                closure := c
                go func() {
                    err := closure.sendMessage(e)
                    if err != nil {
                        s._removeConn <- closure
                    }
                }()
            }
        }
    }
}

func (s *Server) removeConn(c *Conn) {
    s._removeConn <- c
}

func (s *Server) addConn(c *Conn) {
    s._addConn <- c
}
```

**Edit:**

I stand corrected; according to [Damian Gryski](https://twitter.com/dgryski/status/735839074297253889) maps are safe for concurrent reads. The reason that the map order changes on each iteration is "the random seed chosen for map iteration order, which is local to the goroutine iterating" (another [tweet](https://twitter.com/dgryski/status/735852386414170112) of him). This fact does not affect the first edit and suggested solution.

Comment: There is 2nd code example, is it correct in this case?

Comment: No; because you are removing the item in another go-routine which might get started after `notifyAll` has exited and `defer mu.RUnlock()` line of-course got executed. In other words locking your map inside `notifyAll` has nothing to do with what you do inside that inner go-routine.

Comment: I am removing item with mu.Lock(), not just plain removal. Can you tell me how it must be done then?